# Odd behavior using boost serialization, std::tr1::unordered_map, and a custom key

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, hash, unordered-map

I've been investigating some strange behavior regarding the boost serialization of a `std::tr1::unordered_map` with a custom key. Between serializing a key and serializing the `unordered_map` that contains the key, there are 4 different situations from the four members: deserialized key, deserialized `unordered_map`, original key, original `unordered_map`

- using original key with original `unordered_map`
- using deserialized key with deserialized `unordered_map`
- using deserialized key with original `unordered_map`
- using original key with deserialized `unordered_map`

The first two cases work as you would expect, but the last two cases do not map correctly. I've created a minimum working example below. Note that you need the boost header for the `unordered_map` to be serializable. I've attached that at the bottom.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include "unordered_map.hpp"

class HashKey {
public:
    HashKey() = default;
    HashKey(const HashKey& orig) = default;
    virtual ~HashKey() = default;
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & const_cast<unsigned long &>(id);
    }
    inline bool operator==(const HashKey& key) const {
        return this->id == key.id;
    }
    struct KeyHasher {
        std::size_t operator()(const HashKey* key) const {
            return boost::hash<unsigned long>()(key->id);
        }
    };
private:
    static unsigned long int idCounter;
    const unsigned long int id = HashKey::idCounter;
};

unsigned long int HashKey::idCounter = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::tr1::unordered_map<HashKey*,std::string,HashKey::KeyHasher> map;
    HashKey key;
    map[&key]="works!";

    {
        std::ofstream ofs("key.save");
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << key;
        oa << map;
    }
    HashKey newKey;
    std::tr1::unordered_map<HashKey*,std::string,HashKey::KeyHasher> newMap;
    {
        std::ifstream ifs("key.save");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> newKey;
        ia >> newMap;
    }
    std::cout<<"Result: "<<map[&key]<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"Result: "<<newMap[&newKey]<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"Result: "<<map[&newKey]<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"Result: "<<newMap[&key]<<"\n";


    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code when run is:

```
Result: works!
Result: works!
Result: 
Result:
```

I do not understand why the last two cases are not working. I checked the values output by the hash function, and they are correct. I suspect that it has something to do with the `operator()==`for the pointers that are being used as keys, but I'm not certain how to check. I would like to be able to use all 4 cases in my code. Any illumination on why this isn't working? Thanks.

---

This is the `unordered_map.hpp` that is used to serialize the hashmap. This comes from [this boost ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5265). Include it with the MWE:

```
#ifndef  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_UNORDERED_MAP_HPP
#define BOOST_SERIALIZATION_UNORDERED_MAP_HPP

// MS compatible compilers support #pragma once
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1020)
# pragma once
#endif

/////////1/////////2/////////3/////////4/////////5/////////6/////////7/////////8
// serialization/unordered_map.hpp:
// serialization for stl unordered_map templates

// (C) Copyright 2002 Robert Ramey - http://www.rrsd.com . 
// Use, modification and distribution is subject to the Boost Software
// License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
// http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)

//  See http://www.boost.org for updates, documentation, and revision history.

#include <boost/tr1/unordered_map.hpp>

#include <boost/config.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unordered_collections_save_imp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unordered_collections_load_imp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>

namespace boost { 
namespace serialization {

namespace stl {

// map input
template<class Archive, class Container>
struct archive_input_unordered_map
{
    inline void operator()(
        Archive &ar, 
        Container &s, 
        const unsigned int v
    ){
        typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME Container::value_type type;
        detail::stack_construct<Archive, type> t(ar, v);
        // borland fails silently w/o full namespace
        ar >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("item", t.reference());
        std::pair<BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME Container::const_iterator, bool> result = 
            s.insert(t.reference());
        // note: the following presumes that the map::value_type was NOT tracked
        // in the archive.  This is the usual case, but here there is no way
        // to determine that.  
        if(result.second){
            ar.reset_object_address(
                & (result.first->second),
                & t.reference().second
            );
        }
    }
};

// multimap input
template<class Archive, class Container>
struct archive_input_unordered_multimap
{
    inline void operator()(
        Archive &ar, 
        Container &s, 
        const unsigned int v
    ){
        typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME Container::value_type type;
        detail::stack_construct<Archive, type> t(ar, v);
        // borland fails silently w/o full namespace
        ar >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("item", t.reference());
        BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME Container::const_iterator result 
            = s.insert(t.reference());
        // note: the following presumes that the map::value_type was NOT tracked
        // in the archive.  This is the usual case, but here there is no way
        // to determine that.  
        ar.reset_object_address(
            & result->second,
            & t.reference()
        );
    }
};

} // stl

template<
    class Archive, 
    class Key, 
    class HashFcn, 
    class EqualKey,
    class Allocator
>
inline void save(
    Archive & ar,
    const std::tr1::unordered_map<
        Key, HashFcn, EqualKey, Allocator
    > &t,
    const unsigned int /*file_version*/
){
    boost::serialization::stl::save_unordered_collection<
        Archive, 
        std::tr1::unordered_map<
            Key, HashFcn, EqualKey, Allocator
        >
    >(ar, t);
}

template<
    class Archive, 
    class Key, 
    class HashFcn, 
    class EqualKey,
    class Allocator
>
inline void load(
    Archive & ar,
    std::tr1::unordered_map<
        Key, HashFcn, EqualKey, Allocator
    > &t,
    const unsigned int /*file_version*/
){
    boost::serialization::stl::load_unordered_collection<
        Archive,
        std::tr1::unordered_map<
            Key, HashFcn, EqualKey, Allocator
        >,
        boost::serialization::stl::archive_input_unordered_map<
            Archive, 
            std::tr1::unordered_map<
                Key, HashFcn, EqualKey, Allocator
            >
        >
    >(ar, t);
}

// split non-intrusive serialization function member into separate
// non intrusive save/load member functions
template<
    class Archive, 
    class Key, 
    class HashFcn, 
    class EqualKey,
    class Allocator
>
inline void serialize(
    Archive & ar,
    std::tr1::unordered_map<
        Key, HashFcn, EqualKey, Allocator
    > &t,
    const unsigned int file_version
){
    boost::serialization::split_free(ar, t, file_version);
}

// unordered_multimap
template<
    class Archive, 
    class Key, 
    class HashFcn, 
    class EqualKey,
    class Allocator
>
inline void save(
    Archive & ar,
    const std::tr1::unordered_multimap<
        Key, HashFcn, EqualKey, Allocator
    > &t,
    const unsigned int /*file_version*/
){
    boost::serialization::stl::save_unordered_collection<
        Archive, 
        std::tr1::unordered_multimap<
            Key, HashFcn, EqualKey, Allocator
        >
    >(ar, t);
}

template<
    class Archive, 
    class Key, 
    class HashFcn, 
    class EqualKey,
    class Allocator
>
inline void load(
    Archive & ar,
    std::tr1::unordered_multimap<
        Key, HashFcn, EqualKey, Allocator
    > &t,
    const unsigned int /*file_version*/
){
    boost::serialization::stl::load_unordered_collection<
        Archive,
        std::tr1::unordered_multimap<
            Key, HashFcn, EqualKey, Allocator
        >,
        boost::serialization::stl::archive_input_unordered_multimap<
            Archive, 
            std::tr1::unordered_multimap<
                Key, HashFcn, EqualKey, Allocator
            >
        >
    >(ar, t);
}

// split non-intrusive serialization function member into separate
// non intrusive save/load member functions
template<
    class Archive, 
    class Key, 
    class HashFcn, 
    class EqualKey,
    class Allocator
>
inline void serialize(
    Archive & ar,
    std::tr1::unordered_multimap<
        Key, HashFcn, EqualKey, Allocator
    > &t,
    const unsigned int file_version
){
    boost::serialization::split_free(ar, t, file_version);
}

} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost

#endif // BOOST_SERIALIZATION_UNORDERED_MAP_HPP
```

Comment: I don't understand how `newMap[&newKey]` finds something. How does `&newKey` get in there?

Comment: `newKey` is the deserialized version of `key`. The hash operator is overridden for type `HashKey*`. So when the hash function is accessed for `&newKey` it returns the same result as it would for `&key`.

Comment: The hash is the same, but the value isn't. Deserializing `newKey` doesn't change its address.

Comment: @Barry I know that the address of `newKey` is different from the address of `key`, but doesn't the hash function resolve that?

Comment: no, the hash just finds what bucket a key would be in, if it existed. Once it narrows down to bucket, it uses key equality to find the key.

Comment: @Barry Ok, so my suspicion is correct. Is there a way to override the `operator()==` for a pointer of a specific type?

Comment: The 4th template argument to `unordered_map` is `Pred`, which defines how keys are compared.

Comment: @Barry thank you, if you wrap all this up in an answer, I'll accept it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I don't entirely understand what's going on, to be honest, since I don't see how:

```
newMap.contains(&newKey)
```

can be true. Since you're storing the *pointers* to keys, `newKey`'s address shouldn't change when you deserialize it, so it can't possibly be in the new map. That said, what you probably want to do to make everything simpler is just... not use pointers:

```
typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<HashKey,
                                std::string,
                                HashKey::KeyHasher> MapType;

HashKey key;
MapType map;
map[key] = "works";
// serialize stuff...

HashKey newKey;
MapType newMap;
// deserialize stuff...

assert(map.contains(key));
assert(map.contains(newKey));
assert(newMap.contains(key));
assert(newMap.contains(newKey));
```

This would involve fixing your `KeyHasher` to take a `HashKey&` instead of a `HashKey*`. If two keys are equal, they should be interchangeable. If you use *pointers*, you end up relying on pointer equality, which is completely unrelated to value equality (`p1 == p2` implies `*p1 == *p2` but not the other way around).

If you really insist on having the KeyType be `HashKey*`, then you can do:

```
struct Pred {
    bool operator()(const HashKey* a, const HashKey* b) const {
        return (*a) == (*b);
    }
};

typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<HashKey*,
                                std::string,
                                HashKey::KeyHasher,
                                Pred> MapType;
```

But I'd suggest the first way.